# Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.0

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I imported a new app and I get the following error from Gradle (Android Studio):

```
Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.0
```

Here's my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pongodev.recipesapp"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 5
        versionName "3.0.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Main libraries, you always need this libraries in your project. do not remove them.
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

    // Important library to create material design. do not remove this.
    compile project(':materialDesign')

    // Library to create tabbar
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6'

    // Library to create ripple effect. work together with materialDesign library.
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.2.2'

    // Library to create rounded, circle, and any shape image.
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.4.0'

    // Library load lazy images.
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'

    // Library to create simple list.
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'

    // Library to create complex clickable list.
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'

    // Library to create material dialog.
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.0'

    // Library to create animation imageview.
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.5'

}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.1'

Comment: when i do i get a bunch of errors http://uploadpie.com/NWAgY

Comment: Update your build tools to atleast 23.0.0. Currently it is 21.1.2 in your gradle.

Comment: same issue i think we missing something here http://uploadpie.com/ElddT

Comment: You have missed the string "core". It is 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.1'  not 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:0.9.0.1'

Comment: a new error appears holly molly Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: You are now pointing to the site which has a solution in it.. Plz read that.

Comment: im a newbie and i don't have any knwoledge in java can i send u the code and check it i can pay you a sam desposit through paypal if u want

Comment: send ur code to thoughtz.2.reality@gmail.com. By the way payment is not necessary.

Comment: check the email ^^

Comment: did you check it ?

Comment: Fixed grammar, inlined relevant gradle script.

Answer (score 0):

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 5
    versionName "3.0.3"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
// Main libraries, you always need this libraries in your project. do not remove them.
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

// Important library to create material design. do not remove this.
compile project(':materialDesign')

// Library to create tabbar
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6'

// Library to create ripple effect. work together with materialDesign library.
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.2.2'

// Library to create rounded, circle, and any shape image.
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.4.0'

// Library load lazy images.
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'

// Library to create simple list.
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

// Library to create complex clickable list.
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'

// Library to create material dialog.
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.1'

// Library to create animation imageview.
compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.5'
```

}